# Inserting into a single table from multiple tables which don't have any primary key in Oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, external

I should insert into a single table from two different external files which don't have any primary key.

Each external file has different columns. Also, the values should be inserted in alphabetical order. The table in database has a primary key which increments automatically.

Please advise me a way to achieve this.

---

Thanks really for your help...

It's all about inserting into tables which have 1:1 or/and 1:n relationship using external tables...
Each one has a primary key,which is incremented by sequence. I have already inserted into one of the tables"budget" : bu_id,bu_section,etc.

```
insert into Budget (
bu_id,
bu_section
)

select dep.ID_seq.nextval, file1.section
from file1
```

and the result would be like:

```
bu_id   bu_section
1006     blabla
1007     blablabla
```

I want to insert into ("detail") table which has de_id,de_resource,de_comment from two different external files.
In one of them is the resource details and in the other comment.
The insert statement should also take the bu_id and de_id relationship into consideration(the de_id also should start from 1006)

@a_horse_with_no_name: There are more than 1800 records in each external file.  So I think it doesn't work when I use ID_seq.nextval in each of the select statements while inserting into the table.

p.s: I'm not allowed to use SQL*loader.

Comment: Share a piece of code where you already tried to do something. Elaborate the question (or else this question is destined to be voted down or closed)

Comment: agreed - post some effort.  also, you do not insert in alphabetical order - you retrieve in alphabetical order. also, please indicate what programming platform you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, this should do it:

```
insert into real_table (id, col1, col2, col3)
select some_sequence.nextval,
       c1_1,
       c1_2,
       c1_3
from external_table_1
union 
select some_sequence.nextval,
       c2_1,
       c2_2,
       c2_3
from external_table_2;
```

If this is not what you wanted, you need to make your question clearer.

As Randy has pointed out you don't insert in alphabetical order, you **retrieve** rows in a specific order. Rows in a relational table are not sorted. You need to supply an `ORDER BY` expression when retrieving from the real table:

```
select id, 
       col1, 
       col2, 
       col3
from real_table
order by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "Primary key on an external files" (assuming that you are talking about flat files). If you want to Load two "Flat files" and not "Tables", into a single table then start reading about SQL*Loader.

In case you want to insert the contents of two different "Tables" (Table1 and Table2) into one table (Table 3), the answer to this is already posted.